# How to solve encoding problem with japanese characters exportin rails data to csv?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, character-encoding

I'm exporting data to a CSV file in rails and in some of my fields, I'm getting character encoding issues like this when I open in Excel:

[image: Excel file]

I borrowed this code from an example and I'm assuming the encoding is off. Any idea what it should be?

**Controller**

```
@students = Student.page(params[:page])
respond_to do |format|
format.html
format.csv { send_data(@students.to_csv).encode(Encoding::SJIS),encoding: "iso-8859-1",type: 'text/csv; charset=shift_jis', filename: "学生一覧.csv" }
end
```

**Model**

```
def self.to_csv
attributes = %w{ID 本登録日時  郵便番号 郵便番号 電話番号}


CSV.generate(headers: true) do |csv|
csv << attributes

all.each do |student|
    
    csv << [student.id,
    student.full_name,student.email] end
```

Comment: Set encoding to `utf-8` while importing the `csv` file into Excel…

Answer (score 0):

Remove `encoding: "iso-8859-1"` from your code.

Here is how I download Japanese csv in my Rails code:

```rb
  def index
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json do
        render json: paginate(Employee.includes(:skills).order(created_at: :desc, id: :desc).all)
      end
      format.csv do
        send_data Employee.to_csv.encode(Encoding::SJIS),
                  type: 'text/csv; charset=shift_jis; header=present',
                  filename: Employee.csv_filename,
                  disposition: 'attachment'
      end
    end
  end
```